# How to make my heroku app run on https:// rather than http://?

Tags: security, heroku, https

I have an web app running on heroku on a custom domain that seems to be running on http:// by default. Trying to prepend the url with https:// doesn't load the web app. How can I make it so that the app runs on https:// by default?

I tried https://gethttpsforfree.com but I get stuck on step 4 when I try to run the command:

```
sudo python2 -c "import BaseHTTPServer; \
    h = BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler; \
    h.do_GET = lambda r: r.send_response(200) or r.end_headers() or r.wfile.write('owEJmoAzBgnz0Z01_8U0OYC4cQJ1EGi5XMUlYNiY6V0.5J4dX_XNJIPk6rA_h9DwP8Xe41hXdUx8-4JJwmnXEwo'); \
    s = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 80), h); \
    s.serve_forever()"
```

I run this command by prepending it with `heroku run -a appname` in the terminal, but I get `sudo not found`. If I don't use sudo then I get `permission denied`.

Comment: Is your app on custom domain or one assigned by heroku?

Comment: on a custom domain

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management